# Error Importing 2 rows from .csv to Microsoft sql server management

Tags: sql-server, import, ssms, importerror, flat-file

I'm trying to import a flat file, but there is an error when getting to one of the rows:

> Error inserting data into table occured while inserting rows 1483 -
> 1484. Microsoft.SqlServer.Import.Wizard)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Error inserting data into table occured while inserting rows 1483 -
> 1484. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Prose.Import.SDS)
>
> ---
>
> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be
> converted to type nvarchar of the specified target column.
> (System.Data)
>
> ---
>
> String or binary data would be truncated. (System.Data)

---

When I look at the rows in Excel, I see nothing different. I cleaned this information before I tried importing it, so it should be the same. I first tried this with an uncleaned file, and got a similar error.

These are the two files in question, I put back slashes to separate the cells:

> **F58D68CFA3C0433E**\ **electric_bike**\  1/24/2021 18:56\    1/24/2021
> 19:14\    **Lincoln Ave & Waveland Ave**\ **13253**\  **Broadway & Wilson
> Ave**\    **13074**\  41.94881667\    -87.67528067\   41.96492333\    -87.65843033\   **casual**\

> **A6D826302872815D**\ **electric_bike**\  1/22/2021 15:43\    1/22/2021
> 16:15\    **Michigan Ave & Jackson Blvd**\    **TA1309000002**\   **Broadway & Barry
> Ave**\    **13137**\  41.877752\  -87.62406367\   41.93764117\    -87.64388967\   **member**\

The bolded columns are nvarchar(50). Columns 6 and 8 was changed to text because some of the rows contain letters. The others are datetime2 and float.

What do I need to change to get this to work? I have multiple files like this I need to import.

Comment: Try to look at the rows in something like Notepad++ with Show All Characters on.  Maybe there's an unexpected character in those rows instead of your expected delimiter.

Comment: Take those few rows and use the find and replace function in the notepad++ and convert them to a insert statement, eg: convert all back slash(\) to quote comma quote (',') and wrap them in a insert statement and this time it will give you what exact column it is failing on and you can dig from there. And also check if the line seperate is good on the previous line, sometimes, that could trip the ETL.

Comment: After working with scientists and scientific data for over 10 years, my advice: keep delimited file data such as .csv files the hell away from Excel. Excel is very good at breaking file data (especially Unicode characters and anything that could be interpreted as a date such as ISO codes) and hiding problems such as blank columns and rows and excess whitespace. If you need to use a GUI spreadsheet program to manipulate .csv files you should prefer LibreOffice/OpenOffice Calc over Excel, but consider other IDE solutions with extensions such as jEdit and Visual Studio Code.

Comment: I couldn't find anything out of sorts when I put the rows into Note++. When I changed the number of rows to check for errors from 1 to 1000, all of the rows ended up being a problem. So I ended up uploading the tables to Bigquery, and they uploaded when I had the computer guess the schema, but had a problem with columns 3 & 4 when manually choosing the data types, even though it's the same as what the program chose. So I think they might be the problem.